# Allow and disallow the viewpager to swipe only in one direction depending on some condition

Tags: android

I have searched a lot on this topic and found out no working solution. some told to override my viewpager class some told me to take the original viewpager class to my application. i have tried both of the methods but in vain. i want to keep the swipe to right in viewpager disable,  untill a specific condition is true. help me to solve my problem . currently i am overriding my onInterceptTouchEvent() like bellow......

public class CustomViewPagerWithNoRightSwipe extends ViewPager {

```
public CustomViewPagerWithNoRightSwipe(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPagerWithNoRightSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    // detect the swipe to right 

    float x1 = 0;
    float y1 = 0;
    float x2 = 0;
    float y2 = 0;
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        x1 = touchevent.getX();
        y1 = touchevent.getY();
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        x2 = touchevent.getX();
        y2 = touchevent.getY();

        // if left to right sweep event on screen
        if (x1 < x2) {
            if (ViewPagerData.flagTsetNavigation1
                    || ViewPagerData.flagTsetNavigation2
                    || ViewPagerData.flagTsetNavigation3)
                return true;
        }

        // if right to left sweep event on screen
        if (x1 > x2) {
            return true;

        }

    }
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Problems:
 1) viewpager is still swiping to the right.
 2) my childviews in viewpager page(fragment) become unclickable when i use this viewpager class in my xml.

please solve my problem. thanks in advance .